# How can I include a list of strings or an array of strings in one signals rest api "include_player_ids" parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, onesignal

I am using one signals push notification rest api system and I am having trouble understanding how the parameters work. There is an example which I will provide but only with hardcoded data. One signal support team is anything but supportive. I already have a string List 'listIds' and a string[] 'arrayIds' and I want to include the one or the other in "include_player_ids" parameter.

Here is One signal's example code

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{"
                                    + "\"app_id\": \"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c\","
                                    + "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"},"
                                    + "\"include_player_ids\": [\"6392d91a-b206-4b7b-a620-cd68e32c3a76\",\"76ece62b-bcfe-468c-8a78-839aeaa8c5fa\",\"8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86\"]}");
```

I have tried replacing the last line with the following lines but none work. I cannot understand how byte[] and these backlashes work.

```
+ "\"include_player_ids\": " + guestDevicesList + "}");
+ "\"include_player_ids\": " + arrayIds + "}");
```

Providing hardcoded values, the code works. I need some assistance on replacing the hardcoded values with a string List or a string[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was JSON format at first, but apparently it isn't.

```
  var list = new string[]
  {
    "6392d91a-b206-4b7b-a620-cd68e32c3a76",
    "76ece62b-bcfe-468c-8a78-839aeaa8c5fa",
    "8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86"
  };

  var listQuoted = list.Select(i => $"\"{i}\"");
  var commaSeparated = string.Join(",", listQuoted);
  var finalString = $"[{commaSeparated}]";
```

Comment: Im sorry, what does this code do? I understand the join joins the strings with commas and the last line is the final output, but what exactly does "var listQuoted = list.Select(i => $"\"{i}\"");" do?

Comment: It's one way of surrounding each item of the original list with (double) quotes.

Comment: Adding "finalString" like this does the trick + "\"include_player_ids\": " + finalString + "}");

Answer (score 0):

are you using byteArray because you are using  `System.Net.WebClient()`?

I would suggest to use `HttpClient` instead. You can upload using strings instead.

If you really need the byte array, try using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` instead to use `ASCII characters` instead of only `UTF8`.

Comment: I am using it because thats is what the example uses. Can you also set parameters using HttpClient?